# How to compile with gradle different dependency module's dependencies based on build variants?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android app which has a module dependency. This module itself has a jar library as a dependency that comes in two variants, each relative to a build variant of the main app. When I switch build variant in the main app, I managed to automatically select the module's build variant which picks the correct jar, but this is not reflected in the code, where the specific classes from the jar are not found in the build variant specific code.

Here's the related code from the build.gradle files of the main app and the dependency module:

main app - build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    type1 {initWith(debug)}
    type2 {initWith(debug)}
}

productFlavors {
    live{}
    test{}
}

dependencies {
    type1Compile project(path: ':module', configuration: 'one')
    type2Compile project(path: ':module', configuration: 'two')
}
```

module - build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    publishNonDefault true

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    one {initWith(release)}
    two {initWith(release)}
}
}

dependencies {
    oneCompile files('libs/versionOne/mylib.jar')
    twoCompile files('libs/versionTwo/mylib.jar')
}
```

So, when I build `testType1` variant, Android Studio automatically selects `one` variant, and with a clean build it all goes fine. But if I switch to `testType2`, although module's `two` variant is selected, the editor will highlight missing classes and methods.

How can I make gradle pick the right jar when I switch between the app's build variants?

Some considerations: 
The module needs the library, since it uses a few classes that are common between the 2 versions.
I know this may look like bad project design, but it's an app that has been built by different people in different times, and I now have to develop it "as is".

Comment: you can try using th exclude keyword in gradle

Comment: How? This doesn't seem the case, since there's nothing to exclude, I just need to alternatively select two different file dependencies

Comment: `the editor will highlight missing classes and methods` Why? What classes are exactly missing?

Comment: firstly its incorrect to let your app depend on the two same dependency, especially when the differentiation is the version

Comment: @azizbekian in other words, Type1 uses classes only present in jar One, and Type2 uses classes only present in jar Two. When I switch build variant, the Type2 classes can't find the jarTwo objects, because gradle didn't load jar Two, although the module's build Two has been executed.

Comment: `Type2 classes can't find the jarTwo objects, because gradle didn't load jarOne` But should `Type2` objects be dependent on `jarOne`?

Comment: @Remario, I said "versionOne" and "versionTwo" but they do actually contain different classes, not just different versions of the same classes.

Comment: @azizbekian No, Type2 depends on jar2, jar1 doesn't have the classes I use in the Type2 specific source set. (I made a typo in the line you quoted, I edited it, sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found some clues. First of all, my two jars where the same name, in different folders. After renaming the jars to have also different names, gradle manages to pick the correct one after the build variant switch, provided that an additional "Sync project with gradle files" is done. So now it's not immediate, but eventually it's working.